# Inequality in Conjugate gradient method for solving linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, spectral-radius, spectral-norm, conjugate-gradient

Given the system of linear equations
$$Ax =b,$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in R^m$. Let $\widehat{x}$ be the approximate solution solved by Conjugate Gradient Method and setting $\widehat{b} = A\widehat{x}$. Prove that
$$\dfrac{\Vert \widehat{x}-x\Vert_2}{\Vert x \Vert_2} \le \kappa(A)\dfrac{\Vert \widehat{b}-b\Vert_2}{\Vert b\Vert_2},$$
where $\kappa(A) = \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2 \Vert A\Vert_2$ ($\Vert A \Vert_2$ is spectral norm of matrix $A$).

My attempt: Since $Ax = b$ and $A\hat{x} = \hat{b}$ then
$$\Vert \hat{x} - x\Vert_2 \le \Vert A^{-1}(\hat{b}-b)\Vert_2 \le \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2 \Vert \hat{b}-b\Vert.$$
I intend to apply similarly like above but it makes the inequality turn to $\ge$. In addition, I also realize that I still use any step in CG algorithm. But I do not know where I have to start.

Comment: You practically finished. The fact that the inequality turns to $\ge$ is actually correct

Comment: @Exodd No, I mean $\Vert A^{-1}b\Vert_2 \le \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2 \Vert b\Vert$. It yields $\dfrac{1}{\Vert A^{-1}b\Vert_2} \ge \dfrac{1}{\Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2 \Vert b\Vert}$ and this is not what I need to prove the problem.

Comment: $A$ should be square matrix.

Comment: @daw Oh, I forgot it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: $\|b\| = \|Ax\|\le \|A\|\|x\|$

Comment: @Exodd Oh, I see the problem here. Thank you for helping me pass through this difficulty.